# Can I use a swagger tool combine with go-restful for OpenAPI v3?

Tags: go, swagger, openapi, go-restful

I want to generate OpenAPI v3 swagger file, but the rest plugin [go-restful](https://github.com/emicklei/go-restful) doesn't support producing OpenAPI v3, only OpenAPI v2 so I can't produce it by itself.

How can I to work with [go-restful](https://github.com/emicklei/go-restful) to produce OpenAPI v3?
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Check if [entoas](https://github.com/ent/contrib/tree/master/entoas) isn't more up-to-date with the latest [OpenAPI Specification (OAS)](https://swagger.io/resources/open-api/).

OAS (formerly known as Swagger Specification) is a technical specification defining a standard, language-agnostic interface description for REST APIs.